# Inflate Exception Binary XML file line # Error inflating class TextView

Tags: java, android, exception, textview, android-inflate

Ok,I have run into this logcat error a few times while programming. 9/10 it happens on an imageView and I can resolve it by resizing the drawable or placing said drawable in a higher density folder, but this time is much different. Literally just yesterday the app was working fine, but now suddenly when i click a button that loads a fragment this error is called:

```
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class TextView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.figurativefootball.figurativefootball.FlipCardAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FlipCardAdapter.java:67)
        at com.figurativefootball.figurativefootball.FlipCardAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FlipCardAdapter.java:27)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6685)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5869)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
        at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:556)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
        at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4082)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16668)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5439)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16668)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5439)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1858)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16668)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5439)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1191)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:876)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:895)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16668)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5439)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1171)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16668)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5439)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16668)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5439)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16668)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5439)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16668)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5439)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16668)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5439)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2720)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16668)
        at a

the following is binary line #27:

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/playerSetPosition"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/maroon"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and here is the java code
This is inside the adapter where the layout is supposed to be inflated

```
 @Override
    public FlipCardAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                         int viewType) {
        CardView cv =
                (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(
                        parent.getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.flip_card_image, parent, false);

        return new FlipCardAdapter.ViewHolder(cv);
    }
```

I am literally stumped. anything guys?

Comment: please share the complete xml and adapter calss

Comment: I figured it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody has this same issue, I hope this helps:

To reiterate, if this happens on an imageView move your drawable to a higher density folder or resize it.
Sometimes it may obviously just be an xml typo.
In my case, for some reason, after upgrading to android studio 3.0.1 the attribute:
"android:textAllCaps:"true"
Was causing the crash. After removing this attribute everything is back to normal. Why? I have no idea. Must be an android bug in the api